# In tox What is the difference between setenv, and passenv

Tags: pytest, gitlab-ci, tox

I setting up tox to be used in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` in combination with pytest.
I want pytest to run with specific environment that are set in the .gitlab-ci.yml file

In the documentation I found the `tox.ini` configurations `setenv` and `passenv` but I couldn't understand what is the use case for each configuration.

What is the difference? What are the use cases? i.e. when would I want to use setenv over passenv or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setenv` expects you to set a value explicitly:

```ini
setenv =
  foo=bar
```

`passenv` does not require a value to be set -- it should be *passed* from the context in which `tox` is invoked. As relevant background... without `passenv`, any environment variables you may have set before invoking `tox` won't be present in the testing environment created by `tox`!

---

For example, I might have some tests that I know can run locally, but will not work when run in a CI environment. So, in pytest, I might have something like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.skipif(os.environ.get('CI', False), reason="this test won't work in CI")
def test_function():
    ...
```

In this case I don't want to use `setenv` because I still want these tests to run when I invoke `tox` locally, but not in CI. So, I configure `passenv` for this variable to ensure the variable `CI` (which is always present in the CI system) is accessible in the tox environment:

```ini
passenv =
    CI
```

In other cases, I may want a variable to always be set to a specific value whenever `tox` is invoked, for example, the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` variable to ensure output from my tests is not buffered:

```ini
setenv =
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

---

Another unique usecase for `passenv` is that it supports using `*` and `?` for glob-like matching of multiple environment variables. For example, perhaps your tests make use of many [GitHub Actions environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) (which are namespaced with with the prefix `GITHUB_`), you might do something like this:

```ini
passenv = 
  GITHUB_*
  CI
```

Or for [GitLab CI's environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) which are prefixed with `CI_` and `GITLAB_`:

```ini
passenv = 
  GITLAB_*
  CI_*
  CI
```

Lastly, `setenv` values take precedence over `passenv` values. So, even if a wildcard in `passenv` matches a present environment variable, using `setenv` will take precedence over `passenv`, ensuring the variable/value you specify takes effect over any value that may have been specified or matched with `passenv`.

Answer (score 1):

`setenv` is used to set environment variables within the virtual environment.
( set a value to virtual )

`passenv` is used to pass specific environment variables from the outer environment to the virtual environment.
( pass from env to virtual )

Comment: Ok. It is also possible with setenv to pass environment variable from outer environment to the virtual environment with: setenv: KEY={env:KEY:DEFAULTVALUE_FOR_KEY} (https://tox.wiki/en/3.1.3/config.html?highlight=setenv#environment-variable-substitutions) or am I misunderstanding something?